# Problema al Insertar registro Conflicto con llave foranea-SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Al estar realizando pruebas para insertar registros en un Store Procedure dicho Store Procedure lo que hace es que contiene dentro mas Store Procedure los cuales en caso de haber algun error realiza el RollBack a los registros insertados el problema me viene cuando quiero guardar los registros al ejecutar el store procedure me envia un mensaje el cual dice:

> **Error 547 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CONTRATO_CLIENTE". The conflict occurred in database "dbAgendaEvento", table "dbo.CLIENTE", column 'ID'.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El ciclo del Store Procedure es el sieguiente**

1. Inserta en la tabla Clientes y me regresa el ID del registro que se inserto uso el **SCOPE_IDENTITY()**
   para que me traiga el ID insertado en el S.P.
2. Inserto en la tabla Contrato, ahí uso el ID que me regreso el SP de Clientes igualmente uso
   **SCOPE_IDENTITY()** para obtener el ID que inserto en la tabla Contrato.
3. Inserto en la tabla Agenda donde utilizo el ID de Contrato.

Anexo el codigo SQL del Store Procedure

```
                    USE [dbAgendaEvento]
                GO
                /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_MASTER_GUARDA_INFO]    Script Date: 29/01/2021 12:34:10 p. m. ******/
                SET ANSI_NULLS ON
                GO
                SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
                GO
                ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MASTER_GUARDA_INFO]
                (@NOMBRE nvarchar(100)
                           ,@APELLIDOS nvarchar(150)
                           ,@FECHANACIMIENTO nvarchar(10)
                           ,@RFC nvarchar(13)
                           ,@PAIS nvarchar(100)
                           ,@ESTADO nvarchar(100)
                           ,@MUNICIPIO nvarchar(100)
                           ,@DIRECCION nvarchar(200)
                           ,@NUMEROINT nvarchar(10)
                           ,@CP nvarchar(5)
                           ,@TELEFONO nvarchar(10)
                           ,@CELULAR nvarchar(10)
                           ,@EMAIL nvarchar(50)
                           ,@EMAIL2 nvarchar(50)
                           --CONTRATO
                           ,@ID_PAQUETE int
                           ,@ID_SALON int
                           ,@ID_EVENTO int
                           ,@PERSONAS int
                           ,@PRECIO decimal(10,2)
                           --,@ESTATUS int
                           --,@OBSERVACION nvarchar(200)
                           --,@IDCLIENTE int
                           -- AGENDA
                           ,@FECHA_INICIO nvarchar(19)
                           ,@FECHA_FINAL nvarchar(19)
                           --,@ID_CONTRATO int
                           ,@DESCRIPCION nvarchar(100)
                           )
                AS
                BEGIN
                BEGIN TRAN
                BEGIN TRY
                --SE REALIZA LA OPERACION AQUI
                --CLIENTE---------------------------------------------------------------
                declare @fnac date,@fi datetime,@ff datetime
                set @fnac=(select convert(date,@FECHANACIMIENTO))
                set @fi=(select convert(datetime,@FECHA_INICIO))
                set @ff=(select convert(datetime,@FECHA_FINAL))

                --select @fnac,@fi,@ff
                --obtiene el id
                declare @id_cli int,@id_con int
                EXEC @id_cli= SP_GUARDA_INFO_CLIENTE @NOMBRE
                           ,@APELLIDOS
                           ,@fnac 
                           ,@RFC
                           ,@PAIS
                           ,@ESTADO
                           ,@MUNICIPIO
                           ,@DIRECCION
                           ,@NUMEROINT
                           ,@CP
                           ,@TELEFONO
                           ,@CELULAR
                           ,@EMAIL
                           ,@EMAIL2


                select @id_cli
                --select * from cliente where id=@id_cli
                --CONTRATO---------------------------------------------------------------
                exec @id_con=SP_GUARDA_INFO_CONTRATO @ID_PAQUETE
                           ,@ID_SALON
                           ,@ID_EVENTO
                           ,@PERSONAS
                           ,@PRECIO
                           ,'Y'
                           --,@OBSERVACION
                           ,@id_cli
                select @id_con
                --AGENDA---------------------------------------------------------------
                EXEC SP_GUARDA_INFO_AGENDA  
                           @fi
                           ,@ff
                           ,@id_con
                           ,'Y'
                           ,@DESCRIPCION
                COMMIT;
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                --ATRAPA EL ERROR
                IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                --SELECT 'Transaction is Rollback, In Catch Block';
                SELECT
                 ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                    ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
                    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
                    ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
                END CATCH

                END
```

**Asi es como tengo estructurada las relaciones**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ejecuto individualmente los Store Procedure si los guarda exitosamente , pero cuando lo pongo en cascada no, me podrian ayudar por favor! se los agradecería bastante.

**Codigo SQL de S.P. Cliente**

```
            USE [dbAgendaEvento]
        GO
        /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_GUARDA_INFO_CLIENTE]    Script Date: 02/02/2021 09:31:36 a. m. ******/
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        GO
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO
        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GUARDA_INFO_CLIENTE]
        (@NOMBRE nvarchar(100)
                   ,@APELLIDOS nvarchar(150)
                   ,@FECHANACIMIENTO date
                   ,@RFC nvarchar(13)
                   ,@PAIS nvarchar(100)
                   ,@ESTADO nvarchar(100)
                   ,@MUNICIPIO nvarchar(100)
                   ,@DIRECCION nvarchar(200)
                   ,@NUMEROINT nvarchar(10)
                   ,@CP nvarchar(5)
                   ,@TELEFONO nvarchar(10)
                   ,@CELULAR nvarchar(10)
                   ,@EMAIL nvarchar(50)
                   ,@EMAIL2 nvarchar(50))
        AS
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[CLIENTE]
                   ([NOMBRE]
                   ,[APELLIDOS]
                   ,[FECHANACIMIENTO]
                   ,[RFC]
                   ,[PAIS]
                   ,[ESTADO]
                   ,[MUNICIPIO]
                   ,[DIRECCION]
                   ,[NUMEROINT]
                   ,[CP]
                   ,[TELEFONO]
                   ,[CELULAR]
                   ,[EMAIL]
                   ,[EMAIL2])
             VALUES
                   (@NOMBRE
                   ,@APELLIDOS
                   ,@FECHANACIMIENTO
                   ,@RFC
                   ,@PAIS
                   ,@ESTADO
                   ,@MUNICIPIO
                   ,@DIRECCION
                   ,@NUMEROINT
                   ,@CP
                   ,@TELEFONO
                   ,@CELULAR
                   ,@EMAIL
                   ,@EMAIL2)

        Select  SCOPE_IDENTITY() ID
        END
```

**Codigo SQL de S.P.Contrato**

```
            USE [dbAgendaEvento]
        GO
        /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_GUARDA_INFO_CONTRATO]    Script Date: 02/02/2021 09:32:52 a. m. ******/
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        GO
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO
        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GUARDA_INFO_CONTRATO]
        (@ID_PAQUETE int
                   ,@ID_SALON int
                   ,@ID_EVENTO int
                   ,@PERSONAS int
                   ,@PRECIO decimal(10,2)
                   ,@ESTATUS char(1)
                   --,@OBSERVACION nvarchar(200)
                   ,@IDCLIENTE int)
                   AS
                   BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[CONTRATO]
                   ([ID_PAQUETE]
                   ,[ID_SALON]
                   ,[ID_EVENTO]
                   ,[PERSONAS]
                   ,[PRECIO]
                   ,[ESTATUS]
                   --,[OBSERVACION]
                   ,[IDCLIENTE])
             VALUES
                   (@ID_PAQUETE
                   ,@ID_SALON
                   ,@ID_EVENTO
                   ,@PERSONAS
                   ,@PRECIO
                   ,@ESTATUS
                   --,@OBSERVACION
                   ,@IDCLIENTE)
        select SCOPE_IDENTITY() Id_Contrato
                   END
```

Comment: Para poder reproducir tú error, estaría bien tener el código del procedure de inserción de los clientes SP_GUARDA_INFO_CLIENTE

Comment: listo @Javifer2 agregue el sp de cliente y el de contrato

Comment: Entiendo la idea detrás de separar las responsabilidades. Un SP para cada operación. Tienes dos opciones. 1- Lo juntas todo para hacer `Select @IdCliente = Scope_Identity()`; O,  2- Agregar en cada SP un `OUTPUT` parameter para [obtener el valor de los Id's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15). Creo que el 2do método es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías de utilizar parámetros out en vez de el código de retorno del procedimiento. Es igual de simple y las variaciones son mínimas.
Te pongo los dos procedimientos con el parámetro.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GUARDA_INFO_CONTRATO]
(@ID_PAQUETE int
,@ID_SALON int
,@ID_EVENTO int
,@PERSONAS int
,@PRECIO decimal(10,2)
,@ESTATUS char(1)
--,@OBSERVACION nvarchar(200)
,@IDCLIENTE int
,@IDCONTRATO int OUT)
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[CONTRATO]
                   ([ID_PAQUETE]
                   ,[ID_SALON]
                   ,[ID_EVENTO]
                   ,[PERSONAS]
                   ,[PRECIO]
                   ,[ESTATUS]
                   --,[OBSERVACION]
                   ,[IDCLIENTE])
             VALUES
                   (@ID_PAQUETE
                   ,@ID_SALON
                   ,@ID_EVENTO
                   ,@PERSONAS
                   ,@PRECIO
                   ,@ESTATUS
                   --,@OBSERVACION
                   ,@IDCLIENTE)
     
        SELECT @IDCONTRATO = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    RETURN;
END
```

Observa la asignación al parámetro que se ha declarado como out. El return se debería de usar como retorno de la ejecución del procedimiento, no para obtener un valor. No es que no se pueda, sino que no es lo más adecuado. Return devuelve un 0, porque la ejecución ha sido correcta y cualquier otro valor, si no lo ha sido.

[return](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Segundo procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GUARDA_INFO_CLIENTE]
(@NOMBRE nvarchar(100)
,@APELLIDOS nvarchar(150)
,@FECHANACIMIENTO date
,@RFC nvarchar(13)
,@PAIS nvarchar(100)
,@ESTADO nvarchar(100)
,@MUNICIPIO nvarchar(100)
,@DIRECCION nvarchar(200)
,@NUMEROINT nvarchar(10)
,@CP nvarchar(5)
,@TELEFONO nvarchar(10)
,@CELULAR nvarchar(10)
,@EMAIL nvarchar(50)
,@EMAIL2 nvarchar(50)
,@IDCLIENTE int OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CLIENTE]
                   ([NOMBRE]
                   ,[APELLIDOS]
                   ,[FECHANACIMIENTO]
                   ,[RFC]
                   ,[PAIS]
                   ,[ESTADO]
                   ,[MUNICIPIO]
                   ,[DIRECCION]
                   ,[NUMEROINT]
                   ,[CP]
                   ,[TELEFONO]
                   ,[CELULAR]
                   ,[EMAIL]
                   ,[EMAIL2])
             VALUES
                   (@NOMBRE
                   ,@APELLIDOS
                   ,@FECHANACIMIENTO
                   ,@RFC
                   ,@PAIS
                   ,@ESTADO
                   ,@MUNICIPIO
                   ,@DIRECCION
                   ,@NUMEROINT
                   ,@CP
                   ,@TELEFONO
                   ,@CELULAR
                   ,@EMAIL
                   ,@EMAIL2)

        Select @IDCLIENTE = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
RETURN;
END;
```

El "cuerpo principal"

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MASTER_GUARDA_INFO]
                (@NOMBRE nvarchar(100)
                           ,@APELLIDOS nvarchar(150)
                           ,@FECHANACIMIENTO nvarchar(10)
                           ,@RFC nvarchar(13)
                           ,@PAIS nvarchar(100)
                           ,@ESTADO nvarchar(100)
                           ,@MUNICIPIO nvarchar(100)
                           ,@DIRECCION nvarchar(200)
                           ,@NUMEROINT nvarchar(10)
                           ,@CP nvarchar(5)
                           ,@TELEFONO nvarchar(10)
                           ,@CELULAR nvarchar(10)
                           ,@EMAIL nvarchar(50)
                           ,@EMAIL2 nvarchar(50)
                           --CONTRATO
                           ,@ID_PAQUETE int
                           ,@ID_SALON int
                           ,@ID_EVENTO int
                           ,@PERSONAS int
                           ,@PRECIO decimal(10,2)
                           --,@ESTATUS int
                           --,@OBSERVACION nvarchar(200)
                           --,@IDCLIENTE int
                           -- AGENDA
                           ,@FECHA_INICIO nvarchar(19)
                           ,@FECHA_FINAL nvarchar(19)
                           --,@ID_CONTRATO int
                           ,@DESCRIPCION nvarchar(100)
                           )
                AS
                BEGIN
                BEGIN TRAN
                BEGIN TRY
                --SE REALIZA LA OPERACION AQUI
                --CLIENTE---------------------------------------------------------------
                declare @fnac date,@fi datetime,@ff datetime
                set @fnac=(select convert(date,@FECHANACIMIENTO));
                set @fi=(select convert(datetime,@FECHA_INICIO));
                set @ff=(select convert(datetime,@FECHA_FINAL));

                --select @fnac,@fi,@ff
                --obtiene el id
                DECLARE @IDCONTRATO int,@IDCLIENTE int;
                EXEC SP_GUARDA_INFO_CLIENTE 
                            @NOMBRE
                           ,@APELLIDOS
                           ,@fnac 
                           ,@RFC
                           ,@PAIS
                           ,@ESTADO
                           ,@MUNICIPIO
                           ,@DIRECCION
                           ,@NUMEROINT
                           ,@CP
                           ,@TELEFONO
                           ,@CELULAR
                           ,@EMAIL
                           ,@EMAIL2
                           ,@IDCLIENTE OUT

                --select * from cliente where id=@id_cli
                --CONTRATO---------------------------------------------------------------
                exec SP_GUARDA_INFO_CONTRATO @ID_PAQUETE
                           ,@ID_SALON
                           ,@ID_EVENTO
                           ,@PERSONAS
                           ,@PRECIO
                           ,'Y'
                           --,@OBSERVACION
                           ,@IDCLIENTE
                           , @IDCONTRATO
               
                --AGENDA---------------------------------------------------------------
                --EXEC SP_GUARDA_INFO_AGENDA  
                --           @fi
                --           ,@ff
                --           ,@id_con
                --           ,'Y'
                --           ,@DESCRIPCION
                COMMIT;
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                --ATRAPA EL ERROR
                IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                --SELECT 'Transaction is Rollback, In Catch Block';
                SELECT
                    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                    ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
                    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
                    ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
                END CATCH

                END;
```

Ten cuidado, porque yo he comentado la inserción en la agenda, ya que no lo tenía.

Como ves las llamadas, solo utilizan el parámetro OUT en la misma, con las variables. Es importante que el parámetro se llame igual, dentro que fuera.

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_MASTER_GUARDA_INFO]  
        @NOMBRE ='ANA'
        ,@APELLIDOS = 'F'
        ,@FECHANACIMIENTO ='19870101'
        ,@RFC ='RFC1'
        ,@PAIS = 'ESPAÑA'
        ,@ESTADO ='ASTURIAS'
        ,@MUNICIPIO ='GIJÓN'
        ,@DIRECCION ='CALLE 1'
        ,@NUMEROINT = '5'
        ,@CP = '33231'
        ,@TELEFONO ='1234'
        ,@CELULAR ='1234'
        ,@EMAIL ='email@email.com'
        ,@EMAIL2 ='email2@email.com'
        --CONTRATO
        ,@ID_PAQUETE =5
        ,@ID_SALON =1
        ,@ID_EVENTO =1
        ,@PERSONAS =1
        ,@PRECIO =199.2
        --,@ESTATUS int
        --,@OBSERVACION nvarchar(200)
        --,@IDCLIENTE int
        -- AGENDA
        ,@FECHA_INICIO ='20190101'
        ,@FECHA_FINAL ='20200101'
        --,@ID_CONTRATO int
        ,@DESCRIPCION='as'
```

[image: Resultado]